# Moving files into new folder using VB

Tags: vb.net

I have one Log file that keep a full path for *.docx extension every time it's created. The problem is I don't know how to split the file's name from the full path. Before move it, I can select which Path that have been created using CheckedListBox and move it to target folder.

For example in my Log File I store (file has been created: `C:\Users\AsrahLim\Desktop\New Microsoft Word Document.docx`), all I need is the file's name "New Microsoft Word Document.docx" and move it to new folder .

This is my target folder: `C:\Users\AsrahLim\Google Drive`. Below is my code.

```vb
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("Select/UnSelect All")
        CheckedListBox1.CheckOnClick = True

        Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\AsrahLim\Desktop\LogFile.txt"

        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) Then
            Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
            Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
                CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(objReader.ReadLine())
                btnSave.Enabled = True
            Loop
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("File Does Not Exist")
            Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count <> 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1
                Dim SourcePath As String = CheckedListBox1.SelectedItem
                Dim MoveLocation As String = "C:\Users\AsrahLim\Google Drive"
                SourcePath = SourcePath.Substring(SourcePath.LastIndexOf("- ") + 1)

                If File.Exists(SourcePath) = True Then
                    File.Move(SourcePath, MoveLocation)
                    MsgBox("File Moved")
                Else
                    MsgBox("File Not move")
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please insert only the code relevant for the question.

Comment: are you getting errors? what's happening

Comment: @BobSki yes i do getting error in this part, it said "Cannot create a file when that file already exists." :

 If File.Exists(SourcePath) = True Then
                    File.Move(SourcePath, MoveLocation)
                    MsgBox("File Moved")
                Else
                    MsgBox("File Not move")
                End If

Comment: So delete the file from the folder where you want to move the file first, then MOVE it. I do a similar thing in one of my project - but i first check that this FILE is not in the folder where you are copying it, if it is, I delete it, then I move it.

Comment: @halfer I am sorry but I'm still not used to this. I will avoid this in the future.

Comment: Hmm, OK. We get 20 or so explicit expectations of special treatment every day, and I wonder if it is just a cultural difference we have. To a native English speaker it appears to be an attempt to jump to the front of the queue, but perhaps it is different in your locality? Out of interest if you were to approach a stranger and ask for an urgent favour, would it be rude of them not to prioritise your request? I am intrigued by this phenomenon, and would like to understand it.

Comment: (Often when people reply to my link above, they believe I am stating a special Stack Overflow rule. I am not - that merely reflects a discussion here. I would have thought that there is no way, in any culture, that a volunteer may have a urgent obligation forced upon them, given that they are kindly offering their free time. However, I would be fascinated if indeed that is a cultural norm that I am unfamiliar with).

Comment: A better way of getting fast answers is to ask better questions. Be more specific. This should have been 2 questions. 1) “How do I split the file name from the full path?” and only show your split statement. 2) “How do I avoid an exception with File.Move when the destination file exists?” and only show your move statement. If people must read your whole listing, they tend to switch to a shorter question.

Comment: @BobSki: "didn't know they were doing" - but that's the point of my question, wasn't it? I mean, I am all ears - if you think that requests for urgency/ASAP to volunteers _could_ be a simple mistake, then I am keen to learn how you would support that view. I can't see how it might - which is why I asked. I'm not blaming the OP for the level of demanding posts we get here, but they do happen, and I am curious as to what mindset drives it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to implement your own logic for path manipulations. Use the shared [`Path` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx) in `System.IO` instead.

```
Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(SourcePath)
```

Then you can construct the new path name with

```
Dim destinationPath As String = Path.Combine(MoveLocation, filename)
```

---

Also, test if the file exists in the destination location as well and delete it if it exists.

```
If File.Exists(SourcePath) Then
    Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(SourcePath)
    Dim destinationPath As String = Path.Combine(MoveLocation, filename)
    If File.Exists(destinationPath) Then
        File.Delete(destinationPath)
    End If
    File.Move(SourcePath, destinationPath)
    MsgBox("File Moved")
Else
    MsgBox("File Not move")
End If
```

---

*A side note*: I don't like statements like `If File.Exists(SourcePath) = True Then`. Often people think that an If-statement requires a comparison. This is not true. All it needs is a Boolean expression, i.e. an expression returning either `True` or `False`. `File.Exists(SourcePath)` is an expression which does exactly this. The additional `= True` doesn't change anything and is superfluous, because if `File.Exists(SourcePath)` returns `True` then `True = True` is `True` and if `File.Exists(SourcePath)` returns `False` then `False = True` is `False`. `= True` is a neutral operation as is `* 1` for numbers. You don't say `Foo(1 * x)`, you just say `Foo(x)`.

Comment: I think the error might be that you didnt implement that he reads the path from a file with text in front. Thus this is why I had suggested the split idea to take care of that problem.

Comment: `File.Move(SourcePath, MoveLocation) `
- I'm getting error in this part ("**Cannot create a file when that file already exists**")

Comment: It should be `File.Move(SourcePath, destinationPath)` instead of `File.Move(SourcePath, MoveLocation)`, i.e. you must specify the path and filename for the destination, not just the path, otherwise it tries to create a file named like the designation folder. I corrected it in my answer.

Comment: `File.Move(SourcePath, destinationPath)` this is work. Thank u

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes One more question. How to delete the full path in the LogFile.txt after the file have been move?

Comment: Please, post a new question in SO.

Comment: Very very very thanks! I was struggling with this since weeks thinking on how to move across drives. You explained very clearly with an example! Without it, couldn't had understood it really! Thanks a million. I wish I could upvote for this answer n number of times. Sad that I could do it only once

Answer (score 0):

Very simple in your log you could store with a delimiter for instance:

```
New File Created*C:\test.docx
```

The star symbol is a banned character in file name so you can be sure it wont be in the path. After this you can just do

```
Dim data() As String
data = Split(File.ReadAllText(LogFile.txt),  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
File.Move(data(1), Path.Combine(MoveLocation , Path.GetFileName(data(1)))
```

Ideally you just shouldn't store files a bit everywhere on your computer and use distinct folders.